# Replace all occurances of CSS class using Nokogiri

Tags: html, css, ruby, nokogiri

How would I replace all instances of a CSS class that occur within a document on any element with a different class?

There may be other classes on any of elements in which case they should be left untouched.

If the class name was 'foo' and I wanted to replace it with 'bar', I effectively I want to go from:

```
<div class"foo">
 <span class="foo omega"></span>
 <span class="alpha foo omega"></span>
</div>
```

To:

```
<div class"bar">
 <span class="bar omega"></span>
 <span class="alpha bar omega"></span>
</div>
```

I know I could just loop through all the elements and do a replace on the css attribute, but this feels clunky.

Comment: You should show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Meditate on this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<div class"foo">
 <span class="foo omega"></span>
 <span class="alpha foo omega"></span>
</div>
EOT

foo_spans = doc.search('.foo') # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe532115b14 name="span" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe532115a60 name="class" value="foo omega">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fe532115380 name="span" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fe5321152e0 name="class" value="alpha foo omega">]>]
foo_spans.each do |n|
  n['class'] = n['class'].gsub(/\bfoo\b/, 'bar')
end

puts doc.to_html

# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html><body>
# >> <div class>
# >>  <span class="bar omega"></span>
# >>  <span class="alpha bar omega"></span>
# >> </div>
# >> </body></html>
```